# Does the link layer in the TCP/IP stack derive the MAC address of the NICs that are to receive data packets based on the destination's IP address?

Tags: tcp

I am trying to understand the functioning of the different layers in the TCP/IP stack, and I just wanted some clarification on how the link layer derives the MAC address of NICs to receive packets.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a function of TCP/IP, per se.  Instead, the ARP (Address Resolution Protocol) is used in IPv4 to translate the destination IP address to the correct MAC address.

This is accomplished by the stack by first determining if the delivery is local (within the subnet) by comparing the destination to the configured network mask.  If it is local, ARP will be used to generate broadcast frames at the link layer, attempting to resolve the known IP address to the known MAC address.

On the other hand, if the destination IP address is determined not to be on the local subnet, the ARP protocol will be used to send a broadcast ARP at the link layer to discover the MAC address of the router that should be used based on the configured routing table.

Using IPv6, ARP is eliminated and replaced with multicast (more specifically, solicited node multicast) using the Neighbor Discovery Protocol over ICMP6.

Comment: @user9156115 if this answers your question, please accept the answer.